# rails 5.0.7 Multiple default gems and unable to uninstall any default gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had bundler 1.16 installed and rails was complaining that my bundle had previously been created with a higher version of bundler So I installed bundler 2.0.1 with the --default switch but that still left a default 1.16.6 as well I'm trying to uninstall 1.16.6 but I get error can't uninstall a default gem How can I remove it's default flag then? Also if I'm using rails 5.0.7 which ruby version should I use?

Comment: Might also be this thing I bumped into the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123850/mismatched-bundler-version-bundler-2-ruby-2-6

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this, but, in my case, its how i got the issue fixed. So, just in-case this helps.

Initially:

```rb
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, default: 1.16.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

After failing multiple uninstalls, I ran this,

```rb
gem update --system
```

Then,

```rb
bundle version
Bundler version 1.17.3 (2019-08-16 commit d7089abb6)
```

(which is the version i required in my application)

```rb
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to remove the default bundler, you can clobber it like I just did using something like this but adjusted for your ruby's versions and paths:

```sh
rm /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb
rm -r /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/
rm /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/bundle{,r}
rm /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/specifications/default/bundler-1.17.3.gemspec
```

Or, living dangerously:

```sh
rm -rf "$(ruby -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG["rubylibdir"]')"/bundler{.rb,/} \
  "$(ruby -e 'print RbConfig::CONFIG["bindir"]')"/bundle{,r} \
  "$(ruby -e 'print Gem.dir')"/specifications/default/bundler-*.gemspec
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. None of the suggested answers worked for me.
Then I tried to install bundler again -- issue solved.

```
gem install bundler
```

hope it works for you too.

Answer (score -2):

Try

> gem list -d

command to see the gems 
then use

> gem uninstall bundler -v 1.16.6

or

> gem uninstall bundler -v 1.16.6 --default

Comment: I think you meant `gem uninstall bundler -v 1.16.6 --default` I imploded rvm and started over, thanks

Comment: invalid option --default

Comment: right, I reproduce your error, I then installed it with gem install bundler -v 1.16.6 and then uninstall it successfully with gem uninstall bundler -v 1.16.6