# [Trying to Deploy]: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, deployment

Very new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, so apologies in advance. I've found many similar posts to this, but the suggestions haven't worked for me so far.

I get that the Bundler version I'm using doesn't match with the of Heroku when I try to deploy, but can't get them to match.

I tried this and it looked like it would work, but no luck. [You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231667/you-must-use-bundler-2-or-greater-with-this-lockfile)

Does anyone have any ideas, or can you tell me what information you require to give some assistance?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove your `Gemfile.lock`
2. Install old version of bundler, for example

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```

3. Run this bundler in your project directory

```
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

4. Make any commit, for example

```
git commit -am "Bundler 1.17.3 was installed"
```

5. Run

```
git push heroku master
```

6. Smile

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well trying to push to my Heroku project. Found the answer in another question and it worked for me: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile

run: `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2`

Then try push your app again.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sadly this step didn’t work for me, but that above did.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and after seeing another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123850/mismatched-bundler-version-bundler-2-ruby-2-6), I realized that when I upgraded the latest version of Ruby that it was not compatible with Bundler. I uninstalled Ruby, installed Ruby 2.4.5-1 and reinstalled my gems (including Rails). I can now get on Rails and no more Bundler error.