# Bundler could not find compatible versions of bundler - Ruby On Rails **Adding Carrierwave Gem**

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to add the carrierwave gem. Once I put it into my gemfile and run bundle install, I receive this message on the command prompt telling me the bundler could not find compatible versions of bundler. I understand there is already many people out there which have asked the same sort of question, however after trying solutions such as deleting gemfile.lock or running bundle update, it still doesn't seem to be working.

After trying different solutions I am getting the same error as shown on the image.

Any help would be appreciated!

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read 
more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'

gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'

gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger 
console
gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in 
views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.6'

gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
```

Error after running "Bundle Install"
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Yug.png)

**EDIT:**

After trying [Mismatched bundler version - bundler 2, ruby 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123850/mismatched-bundler-version-bundler-2-ruby-2-6/54125881) , i received the following error:

[Edit Error after running bundle binstubs bundler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FYI0.png)

**SOLVED:**

Removed

```
bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
```

from the gemfile.lock and ran bundle install.

Comment: You should share exactly what you have tried. You should show the exact steps you take and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Hard to tell without details of your error, but is it this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54123850/mismatched-bundler-version-bundler-2-ruby-2-6/54125881

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is. That version of bundler isn't compatible. Do gem install bundler -v 1.17.3

Comment: @PaulByrne that did not work. I am receiving the same error on cmd

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal/app folder

```
bunde update
```

and then

```
bundle install
```